# Unable to print out the output of a powershell script in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

C# code that invokes the powershell script:

```
 var src = source;
                var des = destination;
                var THLD = threshold;
                var FileSize = size;
                var script = $@". ""{SCRIPT_PATH}""; MoveCompressFiles -Des ""{des}"" -Src ""{src}""-Threshold ""{THLD}"" -Size ""{FileSize}""";
                using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    ps.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy")
                    .AddParameter("Scope", "Process")
                    .AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass")
                    .AddParameter("Force", true);
                    ps.AddScript(script,true);
                    foreach (var o in ps.Streams.Error)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error" + o.ToString());
                    }
                    ICollection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
                    foreach (PSObject invoke in results)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(invoke.ToString());
                    }
```

My ps1 code:

```
function MoveCompressFiles {
    param($Des, $Src, $Threshold, $Size)

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing 
    $files = Get-ChildItem $Src
    foreach ($f in $files) {    
        if (($f.Length / 1KB) -lt [int32](($Size / 100) * (100 + $Threshold))) {
            Copy-Item -Path $f.FullName -Destination $Des
            Write-Host "Moved file $f"
            Write-Host ((Get-Item ($Des.ToString() + "\$f")).Length / 1KB )
        } 
        else {
            $filesize = $f.Length * 0.8
            $filesize = ($filesize / 1KB)
            #$filesize = [math]::round(($filesize / 1KB), 0)
            $abc = "KB"
            $filesizeSTR = $filesize.ToString() + $abc
            Push-Location $Src
            magick mogrify -path $Des -define jpeg:extent=$filesizeSTR $f
            Pop-Location
            Write-Host "Compressed and moved file :$f"

            #Rescale if still greater than 200 KB
            while (((Get-Item (($Des).ToString() + "\$f")).Length / 1KB ) -gt 200) {
                $img = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile((($Des).ToString() + "\$f"))
                [int32]$new_width = $img.Width * (0.7);
                [int32]$new_height = $img.Height * (0.7);
                $img2 = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($new_width, $new_height)
                $graph = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($img2)
                $graph.DrawImage($img, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height)
                $newImgName = "M".ToString() + $f.ToString()
                $img2.Save(($Des).ToString() + "\$newImgName")
                $img.Dispose()
                $img2.Dispose()
                Remove-Item ($Des.ToString() + "\$f")
                Rename-Item -Path ($Des.ToString() + "\$newImgName") -NewName "$f"            
                Write-Host ((Get-Item ($Des.ToString() + "\$f")).Length / 1KB )
            }
        } 
        Write-Output("moved")
    }
}
```

I want it to return the string "moved" to the C# for each file compressed/moved for the powershell script, the moving/compressing part works fine ,however there's not output on the console that shows that it has been moved and would like to use that as a basis for another thing. I've also tried the

```
                var results = ps.Invoke();
                foreach (var a in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It is " + a.BaseObject.ToString());
                }
```

Comment: this reference URL will helpfull https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C